# Find the general term of the sequence $(u_n)$: $u_1=\frac{1}{2},u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n^2}{u_n^2-u_n+1} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the general term of the sequence $(u_n)$:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}  du_1=\frac{1}{2}\\u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n^2}{u_n^2-u_n+1} \end{array}\right.$$
I try inverse expression:
$$\frac{1}{u_{n+1}}=1-\frac{1}{u_n}+\dfrac{1}{u_n^2}$$

Set $a_n=\frac{1}{u_n}$, then $a_{n+1}=a_{n}^2-a_n+1$.

If know form of $u_n$, inductive reasoning may be useful. I'm not sure. Please help me.

Comment: Lookup [Sylvester's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence).

Comment: $a_n$ is A000058 in  oeis.org.

Comment: Thank you, I got it